# why when retrieving file data using JInputFiles sometimes get an empty array?

Tags: php, joomla

I am developing a task that consists of uploading files, in this context I identified that in some occasions the call to `$files = $application->input-> files->get('files', [], 'ARRAY');` returns an empty array, while `$_FILES` superglobal contains the the file information.

I show the contents of the variables in JSON format

$_FILES

```
{
    "files": {
        "name": ["test.zip"],
        "type": ["application/zip"],
        "tmp_name": ["/tmp/phpwiA9ch"],
        "error": [0],
        "size": [2993308]
    }
}
```

$files

```
[]
```

I have not been able to identify the reason, I originally identified it when trying to upload a 32MB pdf file, I thought it was a file size issue, but then I identified that it happens with a 3MB zip file, I mention here that I have managed to upload other zip files

I share the media settings

Legal Extensions (File Types): zip, bmp, csv, doc, gif, ico, jpg, jpeg, odg, odp, ods, odt, pdf, png, ppt, txt, xcf, xls, ZIP, BMP, CSV, DOC , GIF, ICO, JPG, JPEG, ODG, ODP, ODS, ODT, PDF, PNG, PPT, TXT, XCF, XLS

Maximum Size (in MB): 100MB

Legal MIME Types: image / jpeg, image / gif, image / png, image / bmp, application / msword, application / excel, application / pdf, application / powerpoint, text / plain, application / x-zip

The solution I think would be to make a call to `$_FILES` if the content of `$files` is empty. But I'm interested in knowing the reason for this error

Here the code I am trying

```
public function uploadAttachments()
{
    $application = JFactory::getApplication();

    $files = $application->input->files->get('files', [], 'ARRAY'); // Here some times is empty

    $helper = new Helper();

    $response = $helper->uploadAttachments($files);

    header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($response);
    $application->close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for obtaining an empty array when it is called `$application->input->files-> get('files', [], 'ARRAY');` is because in the `get` method of the `JInputFiles` class it is verified if the file is safe, the verification is done in the static method `isSafeFile`, after trying a series of verifications if some condition not passes then false will return, in consecuense the method `get` will return the default value in my case an empty array.

In the case of the file in which I was testing it is because it identifies the extension `pl` that is noted as: 'These are suspicious text files which may have an executable'

[JInputFile](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/src/Input/Files.php) class

Comment: Please accept your answer if this issue is resolved to your satisfaction.  This is great discovery sharing.  You might like to post this question & answer at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange as well.